# RemoteDesktop from Windows to MacOS

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I'm trying some solution to remotely connect from Windows to MacOS, similary like Windows RDP does it. From my research it seems there are 2 possible ways, either screen mirroring or setting up my Mac with Remote Management through VNC protocol.

Screen mirroring (TeamViewer, AnyDesk, NoMachine) works smoothly, is not laggy at all, problem is that I always see on server computer (MacOS) whatever the client (Windows) is doing. I need server PC to remain locked and ideally client would login with its own user having it's own session like Windows RDP/VNC does it.

VNC seems it does the trick for user having it's own sessions and not just mirroring server screen, however it's very laggy when connectiong from Windows client (I've tried RealVNC, UltraVNC). It works fine when connecting MacOS client to MacOS server.